# Adding shared libraries to static library in gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am creating static library with gcc using:
`ar rcs libMylib.a objA.o objB.o objC.o`

1. How to add shared libraries to the static library, in other words what is the equivalent to the `-lcuda -lopencv_core` option when creating static library?
2. what, if any, is the equivalent to `gcc` option `-Wl,--no-undefined` when creating static library?

Comment: 1: You cannot. A static library has no place where linking information can be placed until you link it into a final library/executable. 2: Same answer. You must link before you can check if there are any missing symbols.

Comment: 1. Your build system should carry over static library linker dependencies to its consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static library is an archive (collection) of object files. Therefore, external symbols remain unresolved. Same as when creating a single object file.

Only when you create an executable or dynamic shared library, you'll fail (or get a warning) for unresolved symbols.